# How to get the type argument to a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

Suppose I've this generic method

```
void ActivateView<T>(ViewCommand command) where T : IPresenter
{
    //code
}
```

And I've an action as:

```
Action<ViewCommand> action = this.ActivateView<DiagnosticPresenter>;
```

Now given `action`, how can I know the type arument to the generic method `ActivateView`? In this case, it should be `DiagnosticPresenter`. So I'm expecting an instance of `Type` equal to `typeof(DiagnosticPresenter)` as:

```
Type type = Magic(action); //what should Magic do?
if ( type == typeof(DiagnosticPresenter))
{
    //I want to do something here!
}
```

Is that possible? How should I implement`Magic()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work for me:

```
public Type Magic(Action action)
{
    return action.Method.GetGenericArguments().First();
}
```

Comment: Yes. I just found that myself after a bit of exploration. Thanks anyway. It just confirmed it.